# How to print button text value on console in Kivy

Tags: kivy

My app just have one button and its text is a random number from 1 to 9. I want to print the button text on console on on_press. Actually, i have minimized my problem, i want to compare the value with a variable, if button.text=5, do something else do_something_else.

My attempt:

```
#!/usr/bin/kivy
import kivy
kivy.require('1.7.2')

from random import random
from random import choice
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

Builder.load_string("""
<Highest>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Button:
            text: root.r1c2
            on_press: root.new()
""")

class Highest(Screen):
    r1c2 = StringProperty(str(int(random()*10)))
    def new(self):
        print self.text


# Create the screen manager
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(Highest(name='Highest'))

class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

But this gives error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say what error you're getting, but one obvious problem is `self.text` doesn't exit.  You are calling it on `Highest(Screen)`, not the `Button`.  To access kv objects from python you would normally tag them with ids and then use `root_widget.ids.id_of_widget`[(see docs)](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#accessing-widgets-defined-inside-kv-lang-in-your-python-code).  An alternative is to use Kivy Properties.

Since you already have a Kivy Property bound to the text of the button, you can just print that out:

```
print self.r1c1
```